# Unitary fusion category and subfactor

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, fusion-categories, unitary-fusion-category

From a unitary fusion category $\mathcal{C}$, there are several ways to make a (hyperfinite II$_1$) subfactor.

1. By [Ha] there are weak Hopf algebras $H$ such that $\mathcal{C} = Rep(H)$. By unitarity (I expect that) $H$ can be chosen with a $*$-structure. Then by [NiVa], such $H$ provides a finite index depth $2$ subfactor,
2. Now, let $R: \mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{C})$ be the right adjoint of the forgetful functor $\mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$, then $R(1)$ is a Frobenius algebra of $\mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{C})$ by [Sh], and (I expect that) this Frobenius algebra has a $*$-structure and (by [Go,Lo,Mu]) provides a subfactor.

**Question**: What is the link between the subfactor mentioned in 2. and the ones in 1.? Is it isomorphic to one in 1.? Any reference about this link?

---

*References*
[Go]  Ghosh, Shamindra Kumar. Planar algebras: a category theoretic point of view. J. Algebra 339 (2011), 27–54.
[Ha] Hayashi, Takahiro. A canonical Tannaka duality for finite seimisimple tensor categories. arXiv:math/9904073
[Lo] Longo, Roberto. A duality for Hopf algebras and for subfactors. I. Comm. Math. Phys. 159 (1994), no. 1, 133--150.
[Mu] Müger, Michael. From subfactors to categories and topology. I. Frobenius algebras in and Morita equivalence of tensor categories. J. Pure Appl. Algebra 180 (2003), no. 1-2, 81--157.
[NiVa] Nikshych, Dmitri; Vainerman, Leonid. A characterization of depth 2 subfactors of ${\rm II}_1$ factors. J. Funct. Anal. 171 (2000), no. 2, 278--307.
[Sh]  Shimizu, Kenichi. On unimodular finite tensor categories. Int. Math. Res. Not. IMRN 2017, no. 1, 277--322.